# Haskell Generating Infinite Stream Based Off Grammar

Tags: haskell, stream

Suppose we have the following grammar:

#x = INT | (#x + #x) 
INT = 0 | 1

Suppose now I would like to make an infinite stream that "contains" every possible form of #x.

Here's what I can think of so far:

```
atomic :: [String]
atomic = ["0", "1"]
--------------------
plus :: String -> String -> String
plus x1 x2 = "(" ++ x1 ++ "+" ++ x2 ++ ")"
--------------------
makeInfiniteStream :: [String]
makeInfiniteStream = atomic : --something
```

I'm not quite sure what goes on the other other side of the colon. I assume it has to involve a function call, but I don't quite see it yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is an almost-duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515191/how-to-enumerate-a-recursive-datatype-in-haskell). Using strings or an ADT makes no significant difference. (I'm waiting a bit to mark this as a duplicate since my vote would close this instantly.)

Comment: Note there's a simple answer that is technically correct, but fails to generate certain elements in a finite number of steps. `makeInfiniteStream = atomic ++ [plus x y | x <- makeInfiniteStream, y <- makeInfiniteStream]`. (Posting as a comment because it's not really useful in practice.)

Comment: Besides @chi's proposed dupe, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23923229/791604) from the same asker. (It assumes the step of enumerating terms is too easy and asks you to give an efficient way to jump around in that list.)

Comment: [related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97539/lambda-calculus-generator/97610#97610). it diagonalizes the product. ( @chepner )